# Pulling a Substring which does not exist in the same position

Tags: substring

I am looking to pull a substring from a Oracle database column using PL/SQL.
The column has a large string value which varies in size for different rows. Hence the substring I am referring to will not be in the same position for each row. But the substring is uniquely identifiable. It will be like "**,RID!1455,**". i.e. It will be preceded by a comma, have RID, followed by a !, followed by a number and then a comma.

I am interested in pulling this number followed by RID. Can you please help me with this. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you looked into regular expressions?  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

Comment: @kbshimmyo - I havent tried it yet. Thank you very much for the link. I will try and let you know if it worked

Comment: @kbshimmyo I have been trying. But for the specific condition I have, am not able to come up with a good solution. The REGEXP_SUBSTR function seems to have a lot of options but since my string wont be in a specific spot all the time, am struggling. Any more help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below query:

Suppose table text1 has column text with string:

dfgggsdRID!3242dfgdfdg

Then below query will give you result '3242':

```
select substr(text, (select (INSTR(text, 'RID!', 1)+4) FROM text1),4) from text1;
```